# is there a way to allow only one active auth session for a user in firebase across multiple devices?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using React for client and Firebase for database, enables multiple users to signup, login and perform various tasks. It was all working well until I have a use case where user shouldn't be able to login from another device at the same time.

Currently, I am using onAuthSatateChange with redux store to store user information.

I tried to store the user status (if user is logged in) in firestore, where I was updating user information upon login and removing this information on logout. But I am looking for if there is a more better approach to handle this scenario.
I am looking, if there is any method in Firebase which can detect this or with the help of google cloud function or admin-sdk I can verify this

Comment: Nothing is built into Firebase to allow this use-case. This has been covered before, so unless you want to share your implementation and ask for help troubleshooting it, your question will likely be closed as a duplicate against those earlier ones.